# Bolt Installation in a sub folder

Tags: installation, bolt-cms

I am struggeling to get bolt running in a subfolder of my main domain. It is working fine under the root but where do I have change the Settings for the subfolder? I just can't find it.

Thank you
Jan

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Bolt in a subfolder, you need to uncomment `RewriteBase /` rule in your .htaccess file. This should resolve your issue.

More on this in Bolt docs: https://docs.bolt.cm/howto/making-sure-htaccess-works#enabling-rewritebase